# Is there a more efficient transducer to convert mechanical energy into electrical energy than electromagnetic induction?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, motors, power-electronics

I know piezo film has one of the lowest efficiency to date when it comes to converting mechanical energy (or stress in the context of piezoelectricity) and motor (magnet and coiled copper wire) seems to be quite efficient. But is there something more efficient than electromagnetic induction? Thank you.

Comment: What is your desired efficiency metric? You listed a number of qualities, but not which is/are the most important or with any weighting. If you are looking for a list, those kinds of questions are discouraged as they are too broad.

Comment: @Ishtana You have edited this question in a way that apparently completely changes the original intent. Why?

Answer (score 1):

In engineering, efficiency is defined as output power divided by input power. Weight, the number of components and other factors may be related to efficiency in some way, but efficiency as an end result is measured only by input and output power.

The most efficient machines for converting mechanical power to electrical power are a wound-field synchronous generators. They are used for automotive alternators, engine-generator sets and power station generators.

The first automotive alternators that replaced DC generators in cars in about 1960 were rated at about 400 watts. Today's automotive alternators can produce 1000 watts or more. The maximum efficiency of automotive alternators is currently about 85%.

Large power station generators produce hundreds of millions of watts. Recently manufacturers began offering power station generators rated 2000 million watts. The largest synchronous generators have an efficiency of 98 or 99 percent.

In general, efficiency increases as machine power rating increases because the physical size makes it easier and because the economic reward is larger for higher power machines. In general, synchronous generators will be 85 to 99 percent efficient with the efficiency being fairly consistently proportional to the power rating.

Permanent-magnet synchronous generators using the latest magnetic materials can be more efficient than wound-field synchronous generators. They generally require a voltage regulating system that cuts into the efficiency gain, but they could still be more efficient at lower power ratings.

Other types of generators are generally less efficient, but they can have other advantages that cause them to be used in various situations.